# Camera preview on small surfaceView not showing the whole camera output

Tags: android

My app is showing the camera preview on one of my activities. I would like to show the camera preview but not taking the full screen, just inside a small box.

The problem is that right now the image that i get from the camera is smaller that I want. For example, when I open it I can only see there my eyes and nose, but I would like to see my whole face.

It's like my surfeceView is acting like a window in a house that only allows me to see part of the views outside. The idea is that in the surfaceView (that does not take the whole screen space) I get the whole camera output but resized in order to fit the surfaceView.

Is that a problem with the camera preview size? Or should I somehow resize the camera output?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should give us some code to find the problem, at least the `layout.xml` file and the class that uses `SurfaceView` and `SurfaceHolder.Callbacks`. For now, you can try the following if you didn't.

In the `onSurfaceChanged` method use the two int parameters width and height to calculate the best size for your preview. You do this with `setPreviewSize` and `getSupportedPreviewSize`.

If you can't fix the issue in an easy way you can also try to use an `ImageView` or a `TextureView` and paint on them the image that you are given from the `onPreviewFrame` callback.